# taskqueue is not working google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

```
 File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 142, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/apps/account/views.py", line 235, in post
    taskqueue.add(queue_name='create-waybill', url = reverse('_api:createWaybill') ,  params = {'key':url_key})

  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 575, in create_rpc
    return apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC('taskqueue', deadline, callback)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 444, in __init__
    self.__rpc = CreateRPC(service, stubmap)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 69, in CreateRPC
    assert stub, 'No api proxy found for service "%s"' % service
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "taskqueue"
```

I am working on google app engine and try to run taskqueue and getting error

i am using django python3

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue

taskqueue.Task(name='create-waybill', url='/_api/createWaybill',params = {'key':url_key}).add()
```

just this one

and

```
path ('createWaybill', csrf_exempt(views.CreateWaybill.as_view()), name='createWaybill'),
```

Comment: Add code showing how you're using/consuming taskqueue. Do you start your app with ```dev_appserver.py```? or do you use ```python manage.py```?

Comment: i am using django4  python3, I am not using dev_appserver.py i am using manage.py

Comment: Now i have add my code please let me know what wrong in this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the bundled services in Python 3, you first have to enable them.
See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access#django) from Google for doing that

Comment: In a doc step 2 main file ? is manage.py is main file or i have to create main.py file in django? please suggest

Comment: You need to add those commands to the file where you create your ```app``` object

Comment: ok i will do this and i will meet you 2maro i am going to sleep I must need this